# AgGrid missing "col" attribute in html

Tags: html, angularjs, ag-grid

I originally used the 2.3.5 version of Ag-Grid which contained a "col" attribute that indicated the relative index of the column for each cell element.  The "row" attribute still seems to exist.  After updating to version 4.0.5, the "col" attribute seems to have been removed from the control.  Is there a way to replace this attribute or some other attribute that can provide the same html index functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at ag-Grid [change log](https://ag-grid.com/change-log/changeLogIndex.php) you can see the following statement:

> Major: Column no longer has 'index' attribute, as the columns moving now has no meaning. Use 'colId' to identify columns.

You are going to have a lots of breaking change with such a big update.